# Consecutive bits in 2D

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the set of the $N \times M$ binary matrices containing $U$ ones (and $NM-U$ zeros).
How many of them contain at least one $n \times m$ sub-matrix with all ones in it ?

I know pretty well how to compute that in the case of a binary string , i.e. for $N=1$, but could not find
yet a suitable strategy to attack the problem in 2D.

Any hint and reference to papers on the subject is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrices can be considered as adjacency matrices of bipartite graphs : an element $i$ of the set of rows is connected to an element $j$ of the set of columns iff $A_{ij}=1$.

The issue is therefore to enumerate a subset of complete subgraphs therein, called bicliques. It looks to be an active research area with keywords :

"Algorithmic graph theory", "Maximal complete bipartite subgraph", "Biclique", "Consensus"...

See for example

This recent mathSE question (related to Burnside formula) [Counting directed bicliques using Burnside's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3496545)

(https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s41109-019-0123-6) where I found for example this early reference : Malgrange Y: Recherche des sous-matrices premières d’une matrice à coefficients binaires. Applications à certains problèmes de graphe. Proceedings of the Deuxième Congrès de l’AFCALTI, pages 231-242 Paris: Gauthier-Villars, 1962

Comment: thanks indeed for the references, I'll have a look at them and come back afterwards

Comment: Possibly interesting as well (https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-110)

Comment: following your links I also found [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.2822.pdf) which is approaching the subject from another perspective