# Counting directed bicliques using Burnside's lemma

Tags: combinatorics, bipartite-graphs, directed-graphs, polya-counting-theory

Let $b_{n}$ be the number of different directed $K_{n,n}$ graphs, assuming that $G$ and $H$ are considered identical when $G$ is isomorphic either with $H$ or with its transpose $H^T$ (i.e. same graph with all edges reversed).

I'm trying to use Burnside's lemma to calculate $b_3$. The symmetry group seems to be $S_3 \oplus S_3 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ (permutations of vertices on each side, horizontal reflection, and reversing the edges).

It's easy to find $b_1 = 1$ and $b_2 = 4$. I've written a brute-force program that outputs $b_3 = 13$. However, when trying to calculate it with Burnside's lemma, I'm getting $\frac{2112}{144} = 14 \frac{2}{3}$. Actually, I've also written a program that uses Burnside's lemma to calculate it, and I've checked this result manually.

The calculation goes as follows:

$(2^9+2^6) + 3*(2^6+2^3)*2 + 2*(2^3+2^2)*2 + 3*3*(2^5+2^6) + 2*3*(2^2+2^3)*2 + 2*2*(2^3+2^2) = 2112$

The factors outside of the parentheses count different types of vertex permutations on both sides of the graph, and the numbers inside the parentheses correspond to fixed points for these permutations, accordingly, without or with both horizontal reflection and edge reversal (there are no fixed points when either of them is used alone, due to odd-length cycles).

Do you have any hint what might be wrong here?

**Edit:**

The sequence is similar to [A091059](http://oeis.org/A091059), but it's not the same. My program can successfully calculate this sequence (up to the 14th element, then it's getting too slow) when I tell it not to take horizontal reflection into account. This suggests something might be wrong with the reflection, I just still can't see why.

Let's consider directed $K_{2,2}$ graphs. A091059 says there are $5$ such graphs, and we can draw them:

[image]

But the last two graphs are isomorphic – they are just mirror reflections of each other. So $b_2 = 4$.

Comment: Isn't horizontal reflection just a composition of permutations?

Comment: Permutations are independent for the left and right side of the graph, they don't cover every possible isomorphism.

Comment: Your last two graphs show a *vertical* reflection (interchanging the roles of left and right).  A horizontal reflection instead would be performing the same permutation on the left and right.

Comment: I meant to say that horizontal reflection would mean the same reversing (not arbitrary) permutation $(n,n-1,\dots,1)$ on the left and right.

Comment: English dictionaries say otherwise, e.g. https://www.mathwords.com/h/horizontal_reflection.htm.

Comment: Hmm, sorry that I forgot the confusing convention that horizontal reflection means reflection across the vertical axis.  I think we're on the same page now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we  have here is  an instance  of **Power Group  Enumeration** as
described by Harary and Palmer, *Graphical Enumeration*. The algorithm
is       documented       at       the       following       [MSE-link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/).   We  require  the
cycle index $Z(Q_n)$ of the action on the edges of the permutations of
the  two parts  of  the  graph, possibly  combined  with a  horizontal
reflection.  This is the slot  permutation group.  We distribute edges
of one of $k$ colors into these slots, and the group acting on them is
the  symmetric  group  with  cycle index  $Z(S_k)$.  The  cycle  index
$Z(Q_n)$     was    computed     at     the    following     [MSE-link
II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151538/). We have e.g.

$$Z(Q_3) = {\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{9}}{72}}
+1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{3}
+1/8\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{4}+1/4\,a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}
+1/9\,{a_{{3}}}^{3}+1/3\,a_{{3}}a_{{6}}.$$

and

$$Z(Q_4) = {\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{16}}{1152}}
+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{2}}}^{4}}{96}}
+{\frac {5\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{6}}{96}}
+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{3}}}^{4}}{72}}
+{\frac {17\,{a_{{2}}}^{8}}{384}}
\\ +1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{6}}
+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}
+1/18\,a_{{1}}{a_{{3}}}^{5}
+1/6\,a_{{1}}a_{{3}}{a_{{6}}}^{2}
\\ +1/24\,{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{6}}}^{2}
+{\frac {19\,{a_{{4}}}^{4}}{96}}
+1/12\,a_{{4}}a_{{12}}+1/8\,{a_{{8}}}^{2}.$$

With these ingredients  we are ready to run the  **PGE** algorihm. We
get for two swappable types of edges the sequence

$$1, 4, 13, 104, 1507, 64203, 8426875, 3671999389, 5366787092478, 
\\ 26433809041087192, 441089058039611200394, 
25113998661290096278734134, \ldots$$

and for three types

$$1, 6, 84, 7946, 5413511, 25231086540, 800871112032930, 
\\ 177544715836044855636, 281653040526999655665449719, 
\\ 3266495639384107667257990172349726,
\\ 282129919925994006382238965837655927175534,
\\ 184379837924757642947198903200667422197524750679153,
\ldots $$

The Maple code for this is quite compact and shown below.

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local l;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_knn :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local cindA, cindB, sind, t1, t2, term, res,
    cmb, len, l1, l2, cycs, uidx, vidx,
    u, v, inst1;

    if n=1 then
        sind := [a[1]];
    else
        sind := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    cindA := 0;

    for t1 in sind do
        for t2 in sind do
            res := 1;

            for u in indets(t1) do
                l1 := op(1, u);

                for v in indets(t2) do
                    l2 := op(1, v);

                    len := lcm(l1, l2);
                    res := res *
                    a[len]^(degree(t1, u)*degree(t2, v)
                            *l1*l2/len);
                od;
            od;

            cindA := cindA + lcoeff(t1)*lcoeff(t2)*res;
        od;
    od;

    cindB := 0;

    for term in sind do
        res := 1;

        # edges on different cycles of different sizes
        for cmb in choose(indets(term), 2) do
            u := op(1, cmb); v := op(2, cmb);

            l1 := 2*op(1, u); l2 := 2*op(1, v);
            res := res *
            a[lcm(l1, l2)]^((l1*l2/2/lcm(l1, l2))*
                            degree(term, u)*degree(term, v));
        od;

        # edges on different cycles of the same size
        for u in indets(term) do
            l1 := 2*op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            # a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1*l1/2/l1)
            res := res *
            a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1/2);
        od;

        # edges on identical cycles of some size
        for u in indets(term) do
            l1 := 2*op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            if type(l1/2, even) then
                # a[l1]^((l1/2)^2/l1);
                res := res *
                (a[l1]^(l1/4))^inst1;
            else
                # a[l1/2]^(l1/2/(l1/2))*a[l1]^(((l1/2)^2-l1/2)/l1)
                res := res *
                (a[l1/2]*a[l1]^(l1/4-1/2))^inst1;
            fi;
        od;


        cindB := cindB + lcoeff(term)*res;
    od;

    (cindA+cindB)/2;
end;

knn_swap_edge_cols :=
proc(n,k)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_cols, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n = 1 then
        idx_slots := [a[1]];
    else
        idx_slots := pet_cycleind_knn(n);
    fi;

    if k = 1 then
        idx_cols := [a[1]];
    else
        idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(k);
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_slots do
        for term_b in idx_cols do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*inst_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer and references. I think I will have to read the book to fully understand your approach. As for now, the most interesting thing for me is the cycle index. I've looked at you answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165824/477619 and it seems that you used the same index cycle to obtain the sequence https://oeis.org/A007139, which resembles "my" sequence ($13 \rightarrow 26$, $1507 \rightarrow 3014$ etc.). Now I'm trying to understand how to construct the cycle index without considering all $n!*n!*2$ permutations.

Comment: It is very important that you study the [quoted MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151538/) for MSE 1151538 carefully. We are never iterating over all elements of $S_n$, and instead always using conjugacy classes, iterating over the terms in the cycle index $Z(S_n)$ of the symmetric group $S_n$. The same is true for the code shown above. I would never have been able to compute as many terms of these sequences otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your $b_n$ should be the same sequence as [OEIS A091059](http://oeis.org/A091059), which counts the number of $n \times n$ matrices over symbol set $\{1,2\}$ equivalent under any permutation of rows, columns, or the symbol set.  The correspondence is:
\begin{align}
\text{left node} &\leftrightarrow \text{row}\\
\text{right node} &\leftrightarrow \text{column}\\
\text{edge from left to right} &\leftrightarrow 1\\
\text{edge from right to left} &\leftrightarrow 2
\end{align}

But the OEIS entry has $b_2=5\not=4$ and $b_3=18\not=13$.  Maybe the discrepancy is because of the horizontal reflection, which I think should not be included.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This sequence is close, but I think the reflection is necessary to find all isomorphic graphs. I've clarified it in the question.

Comment: OK, in terms of matrices, this additional operation is transpose.  It makes the $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$ equivalent.

Comment: Actually, you need to transpose the matrix and exchange all the symbols to get the matrix for a reflected graph. But generally yes, A091059 with the transpose operation should give us the same sequence.

Comment: I've found $b_4 = 104$ using two different brute-force programs, counting graphs and matrices. Unfortunately the OEIS doesn't know the sequence $1, 4, 13, 104$. And meanwhile my Burnside's lemma solution outputs $\frac{263328}{2304} = 114\frac{7}{24}$ :)

Comment: By considering matrices, I obtained $b_3=((1+0)2^9+(6+6)2^6+(9+0)2^5+(8+18)2^3+(12+12)2^2)/144=1872/144=13$.  The second number in each coefficient corresponds to transposing. Maybe you can track down your error by comparing coefficients of powers of 2.

Comment: It seems that I oversimplified how the horizontal reflection works together with permutations of vertices. When the reflection is involved, some permutation pairs, like ([1,2][3], [1,2][3]) and ([1,2][3], [1,3][2]), behave quite differently and result in different numbers of fixed points, but I considered them equivalent because of the same cycle notations. When I consider each pair of permutations separately, my program works correctly, though much slower. I have yet to find a better approach for calculating this.